# Reference to Object not working in PHPUnit, but does in normal PHP execution

Tags: phpunit

PHP 5.3.10, PHPUnit 3.6.10

I am calling code in a test that fails to initialize an object so that a method may be used from it.  The problem is this is legacy code, and this function is constantly used in our application. It works under PHP natively, but not when run from within PHPUnit.  The calls access a PHP Extension we have for our application.
A Very simple example to demonstrate the issue is below.

Class file to wrap calls to our PHP Extension (FOO):

```
class FOO
{
    $private $Bar;

    pubilc function __construct()
    {
        $this->Bar = new OurPHPExtensionObject();
    }

    public function Option1($Variable)
    {
        return $this->Bar->OurPHPExtensionMethod($Variable);
    }

    public function _Option1($Variable)
    {
        return $Variable; // Dummy to test that code is loaded
    }
}
$Bar = new FOO();
```

This creates the object and loads initial data so it is only done once.  Other calls to use this include a file which then includes this class.  As the application continues to run, the only initialization is done the first time, then the global keyword is used to reference this object to access it's methods.

Function.php example:

```
require_once('FOO.class');
function CausesError($Parameter)
{
    global $Bar;    // Using $Bar defined from FOO.class
    $ErrorCreated = $Bar->Option1($Parameter);  // Call Option from Class
}
```

Then, individual programs simply inclde the Function.php file with require_once() to ensure there is only 1 instance of the file loaded from anywhere.

Sample File:

```
require_once('Function.php');
echo CausesError('Variable Text') . "\n";
```

This causes the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Option1() on a non-object in ...
```

Being new to PHPUnit, and trying to minimize changes to the existing code until I can get the tests in place, I need some suggestions on how to handle this.  A large amount of the existing code is calling this function by simply including the Function.php, then calling the function (CausesError).  I am not sure how to get this to return the data.

My test file then has a setUp() method before each test.

```
class TEST_Function extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        require_once('Function.php);
        echo _Option1('Sample') . "\n"; // Works and ECHOs to show code loaded
        echo Option1('Sample2') . "\n"; // Fails with the error
    }

    public function testFunctionOption1()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(Option1('English'), 'English'); // Error
    }
}
```

Should I mock the function in my test? I am not sure which tests may include this since the function is used through out the code.

Hope this describes the environment and code layout.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through your question I'd assume that you're running into some other problem:

```
require_once('Function.php');
```

will ensure the file is loaded only once. So the assignment of `new FOO` to `$Bar` is done only once. As that variable therefore only exists within the scope of a single test function, it's only available with in the `setUp()` function.

But this might not be the case, more specifics are missing to properly say what goes on behind the scenes as you have not posted the definition of `_Option1()` and `Option1()`.

Comment: Sorry, tried to shorten the example to show what we are doing in the code that works in PHP, but not in PHPUnit.  If you look in the FOO.class, the text passed to Option1 and _Option1 are simply returned for this example.  Option1 uses the PHP Extension we have, while _Option1 is simply a dummy to return text, but used by code validation to ensure all text is preprocessed accordingly.  Your insight on the only available once may help though.  Let me look into that, and possibly include the file differently.

Comment: @StevenScott: But you still need to add the defitions to the question, because otherwise - as I wrote - no specifics are given and your explanation is not specific enough. Definition is code, not talking about code.

Comment: The main problem seems to be the testing of globals/singletons. We have those in use, which are what we are trying to initiate, hence the test.  The functions in question were defined in the FOO.class though. Simple text returns at this point, just one is coming from the PHP Extension we created.  The code in the extension process the passed text and returns the modified text.  We do not want to initialize the listing of text everytime, which is what the singleton is for.

Comment: @StevenScott: One point after the other. What about solving the concrete problem first (`$bar` does not exist) and then discussing how to reduce the cost of initializing the test harnish?